# Map a function at the lowest level

Tags: map

How do I map a function to the lowest level of any given nested list? As an example, how do I create `output` from `input` in the code below?

```
input = {{a, b}, {{c}, {d, {e}, {{f}}}}}
output = {{F[a], F[b]}, {{F[c]}, {F[d], {F[e]}, {{F[f]}}}}}
```

[image]

Comment: [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) takes a level-spec: `Map[F, input, {-1}]`.